# DataGrid - "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath."

Tags: c#, wpf, xpath, datagrid

I would like to display on DataGrid my object database

```
public class Student
{
public string Imie { get; set; }
public string Nazwisko { get; set; }
string Numer { get; set; }

internal List<Telefon> Telefony { get; set; }
internal Adres Adres { get; set; }
}
```

In **Adres** and **Telefon** class I have obviously some extra fields.

My XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Student}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnding="dataGrid_CellEditEnding" CurrentCellChanged="dataGrid_CurrentCellChanged" PreviewKeyDown="dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Imie"        Binding="{Binding Imie}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nazwisko"    Binding="{Binding Nazwisko}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Numer"       Binding="{Binding Numer}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ulica"       Binding="{Binding Adres.Ulica}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="KodPocztowy"       Binding="{Binding  Adres.KodPocztowy}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Miasto"       Binding="{Binding Adres.Miasto}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tel. Numer"       Binding="{Binding Telefon.Numer}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tel. Operator"       Binding="{Binding Telefon.Operator}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I can easily get and set **Imie**, **Nazwisko** and **Numer** fields but when i'm trying to set value of **Ulica** (field in **Adres** class) compiler gives me this exception:

```
InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect **`Adres` bound property is null** so when you try to edit the column value for binding `Binding="{Binding Adres.Ulica}"`, it tries to set value for Adres.Ulica but Adres itself was null. Hence binding fails silently on load.

You have to **make sure `Adres` is initialized for all binded objects** so that you can edit the value for it's child property `Ulica` from dataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

In your view model both `Telefony` and `Adres` properties are declared as `internal`. Try changing these properties to `public`. Check for [Binding Source Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#binding_sources)

> You can bind to **public properties**, sub-properties, as well as indexers

You've also mentioned that you can get `Numer` to work but in the sample code it appears to be declared as `private` which is not valid binding source.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the .(dot) in the binding member name.
Please refer to:
[Binding to fields containing a period in DataTable in C#/WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979155/binding-to-fields-containing-a-period-in-datatable-in-c-wpf)