# WPF bind DataGridTextColumn to EF Core navigation properties

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core, binding

I have a DataGrid that is bound to a collection of an object that has navigation properties.

When I add new rows the properties are null and it throws an exception

> 'Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.'

DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="locations" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,2,3,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customer.Locations}" Grid.Row="1" CanUserAddRows="True" IsReadOnly="{Binding ElementName=submit, Path=IsChecked}"  HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Name"  Binding="{Binding OrderContact.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Phone"  Binding="{Binding OrderContact.Phone, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Email"  Binding="{Binding OrderContact.Email, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Receiving Name"  Binding="{Binding ReceivingContact.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Receiving Phone"  Binding="{Binding ReceivingContact.Phone, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Receiving Email"  Binding="{Binding ReceivingContact.Email, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address Line 1"  Binding="{Binding HouseStreetApt, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="City"  Binding="{Binding City, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="State"  Binding="{Binding State, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Zip"  Binding="{Binding Zip, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Delivery Time"  Binding="{Binding DeliveryTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"  Binding="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Object

```
public class Location : Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Contact OrderContact { get; set; }
    public Contact ReceivingContact { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryTime { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public File Image { get; set; } 
}
```

`OrderContact` and `ReceivingContact` are being displays if it has records in the database but on new rows it trows the above exception.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258860/two-way-binding-requires-path-or-xpath-when-edit-wpf-datagrid) answer that says to initialize the objects in the constructor like this:

```
public class Location : Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Contact OrderContact { get; set; }
    public Contact ReceivingContact { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryTime { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public File Image { get; set; }

    public Location()
    {
       OrderContact = new Contact();
       ReceivingContact = new Contact();
    } 
}
```

but when I do this it works for new rows but for existing rows it is getting empty objects as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757594/ef-codefirst-should-i-initialize-navigation-properties) answer that it overwrites the EF object

[image]

How can I initializes the objects on a new row but still get the object from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try turning those navigation properties into properties with backing fields like so:

```
public class Location : Address
{
    private Contact _orderContact;

    public Contact OrderContact
    {
        get
        {
            if(_orderContact == null) 
            {
                _orderContact = new Contact();
            }
            return _orderContact;
        }
        set { _orderContact = value; }
    }
}
```

This way, whenever WPF tries to get the property, it'll never receive `null`. However, if EF does in fact set those properties, it'll work as it normally would.