# Why I cannot set datagrid cell value if this column's header contains a dot?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

My wpf app xaml is simple, only a datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UserCollection}"/>
```

In code behind, UserCollection is a DataTable:

```
private DataTable userCollection;
public DataTable UserCollection
{
    get { return this.userCollection; }
    set
    {
        this.userCollection = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

In ViewModel.cs, code is simple, create 2 columns and add a row:

```
this.UserCollection = new DataTable();
UserCollection.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));
UserCollection.Columns.Add("co.l2", typeof(int));

var r=UserCollection.NewRow();
r["col1"] = 1;
r["co.l2"] = 2;
UserCollection.Rows.Add(r);
```

But the 2nd column which hearder contains a dot cannot display the value in UI, you can see the picture.

Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, replace dot char to another char by using :

```
StringNameWithDot.Replace(".", "\x2024");
```

Wpf datatable column header cannot contain ".","/","[]", here is another link:

[What is it about DataTable Column Names with dots that makes them unsuitable for WPF's DataGrid control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940618/what-is-it-about-datatable-column-names-with-dots-that-makes-them-unsuitable-for)